# Circle of prisoners

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I do not know if the following game is well-defined:
Suppose that there are $n$ prisoners standing in a circle one after other $n\geq 2$ everyone holding a **silent** gun.
When a bulb lights all either kill the one standing before him or not in some time interval of a few seconds. You are the $1st$, w.l.o.g.W hat are all Nash Equlibria of this game on $n$ players the strategy for each $p\in[0,1]$ killing the one before you with probability $p$. If $n=2$ the one NE is $(1,1)$ i.e. hoping that you will kill your enemy first. If $n=3$ it is good not to kill the one in front of you hoping that she will kill the one behind you. So I think one NE is $(0,0,0).$ What are all NE in general for $n$ arbitrary (in mixed strategies) ?

If the definition of the game leaks somewhere someone may fix it.
**EDIT**
A less macabre way:

All $n$ free people have hats on their heads. Everything goes like above but with taking off their heads instead of shooting. If your hat remains you win 1$. If someone has n hat she is not allowed to take off the hat in front of him.

Comment: Couldn't you have illustrated the problem in a less macabre way ?

Comment: @Peter Oh yes, with hats or something ? It is based of a veru nice but brutal film I saw yesterday. Please, suggest some other setting.

Comment: The hat-version is nice.

Comment: Not sure I understand the rules.  What is $p$?  Do you mean that if I try to shoot my clockwise neighbor they are eliminated with probability $p$ and they survive with probability $1-p$?  If my immediate clockwise neighbor is gone, can I shoot the next one or are my options done with?  At the end of the allotted time, are all survivors freed?  What advantage do I get from eliminating my neighbor?  In the $n=3$ case, don't I profit from leaving them be (on hopes they eliminate my counterclockwise neighbor)?

Comment: @lulu No you are not allowed to shoot the next one. And yes after that time all remaining are freed.And yes, they are eliminated with probability $p$ and missed with $1-p$. That is exactly my question if the only NE is to leave your clockwise neighbor with $p=0$. It may be the case that you may profit from killing your neighbor because he might have eliminated someone next who will actually save you.

Comment: So...I gain nothing from the death of my clockwise neighbor?  Why would I shoot them?  I had assumed that you were trying for a Last Man Standing sort of thing, though of course that just becomes a speed contest.

Comment: @lulu For the first question read my comment above. For the second the game should be fixed somehow so as it doesn't become speed quest.

Comment: I don't get it.  Absent the speed component, I don't see how I profit (I am assuming that my utility function doesn't see an abstract positive in killing for its own sake).  Given the speed component, maybe you could argue that I'd like my counterclockwise neighbor, $X$,  to be gone (as I don't trust him) so I would like to eliminate the person who might eliminate the person who might eliminate $X$ but if we all fire (or not) at the same instant, even this does me no good.

Comment: @lulu Yes, you are beginning to understand what I mean. Your first sentence is correct whith what you say "no killing for it's own shake". So how to incorporate into the game that thing that solution will be based on this:  you want to eliminate the person who might eliminate the person who might eliminate 1st ? So how to fix the presence of the time interval ? You may suggest a completely other setting , perhaps not so macabre.

Comment: As I say, I think the rules need to be substantially rewritten or at least clarified.  Usually in these cases, inertia doesn't guarantee freedom.  But if you change the rules to say "this scenario repeats until we've got a Last Man Standing, or until everyone is gone" then of course I must fire whenever I can (as must everyone else).

Comment: @lulu The fixing of the time argument might be this: what if you have a missing your neighbor option which is high if you shoot too early ? So if you shoot at the time of the bulb lights oh, you miss with probabiloity $q=1$.

Comment: @lulu This is not Last Man Standing. All are freed right after 1st round who survived.

Comment: @lulu So the rules are: one round, missing is a differenatiable function of the time interval $q:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ (the bulb lights at 0) with $q(0)=0$ and $q(1)=1$ and a probability $p\in [0,1]$ that it is a NE that ith shoots.The task find all situations (strategy profiles for all n players) with $q$ commonly known.Shall I include this comment into the OQ ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see it.  The moment anyone fires (be they successful or not) everyone loses any  motive for firing (since even success has no impact on the only person who poses a direct threat).  Nash games don't do well with a timing element, they tend to devolve either into inertia or into instant actions.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @lulu Could you please elaborate more your last comment ? Why "even success has no impact on the only person who poses a direct threat" ?

Comment: If a person can only shoot once and has either successfully eliminated their neighbor or has wasted their shot, then there is no point in any one else shooting.   After all, the only point of shooting is in a domino situation but dominos don't work after one domino is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure the discussions in the comments have really clarified the time element. I’ll interpret the question to mean that the players shoot at different times and the order in which they shoot is random. The exact distribution of the possible shooting orders is irrelevant as long as there’s a non-zero probability for each of the $n$ orders where the shooting goes around the table in the “forward” direction.

Everyone not shooting is always a Nash equilibrium, as nothing is to be gained if no one else shoots. In fact, any strategy profile in which two consecutive players don’t shoot is a Nash equilibrium, as neither of them can gain from shooting instead (one because she won’t get shot anyway, and the other because his target won’t shoot anyway) and no one can influence their own chance of being shot if these two break the chain.

For odd $n$, the strategy profiles in which a single player shoots with probability $0$ are also Nash equilibria, since that player would only be making it worse for themselves (making it worse? how could it be worse?!) if they increase that probability, and no one else can influence their own chance of being shot because of the break in the chain. If all players shoot with non-zero probabilities, they can all gain from lowering their probability, so such a strategy profile isn’t a Nash equilibrium.

However, for even $n$, a single player with probability $0$ gains by increasing that probability, and once they close the chain, everyone gains from increasing their probability, so in this case the only Nash equilibrium in addition to the ones with two consecutive non-shooters is the one where everyone shoots with probability $1$.